How to plot an elongated ellipse in MATLAB?
I need to plot something like a baguett in Matlab. This is my plot function for an ellipsoid:
[theta,phi] = ndgrid(linspace(0,pi),linspace(0,2*pi));
x = l*sin(theta).*cos(phi);
y = 1*sin(theta).*sin(phi);
z = d*cos(theta);
axis equal;
daspect manual
surf(x,y,z)

I was thinking of plotting an ellipsoid and 'stretch' it by manipulating the a,b,c parameters. However, I'm getting the same image even when I change the parameters. Axis just change their values but the image stays roughly the same size, like a square. I was expecting it to look bigger if one axis is from 1 to 10 and another just from -1 to 1. I tried using axis equal or daspect manual or setting xlim, ylim, zlim but nothing worked.
Could somebody please help? Thanks in advance.

axis equal should be after surf, not before. That's why it's not doing anything. Also, in the code you haven't defined l and d.
